# Kinetic Data Structure

Tags: data-structures, computational-geometry

Currently i am studying Kinetic Data Structure thesis by Julian Basch. I am feeling stuck in some points. Are there any other  resources to understand it properly ??

Edit:- I am very new to this data structure. Are there any blogs or video tutorial to understand an introduction to the concept which  is a bit more in depth than the Wikipedia page.

Comment: (Does said thesis provide references?)

Comment: This sounds pretty broad to me.  Any community votes?  Generally we're looking for specific questions.  The resources might depend on what specifically you are trying to understand.

Comment: This indeed sounds pretty broad. Perhaps the question can be changed to ask for an introduction to the concept that is a bit more in depth than the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_data_structure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we should consider a *dynamic data structure*. Such a data-structure keeps some sort of record during a sequence of modifications, usually insertions and deletions. The main idea is that this data structure only needs to do a little bit of work for each insertion and deletion, and therefore is more efficient than recomputing a static data structure after each modification.

A *kinetic data structure* is a variant on a dynamic data structure, where the modifications are of a geometrical nature. Often, the underlying data is a pointset in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and the modifications correspond to small movement of these points. Again, the idea is to ensure these small modifications only require a small number of changes in the data structure, such that we are much faster than recomputing the data structure after each movement step.